# Tabbed Property View - different properties in different tabs from same IPropertySource

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am currently trying to put more tabs in the Tabbed Properties View as per [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html), and from the same implementing class of IPropertySource I want to take out different properties for each tab.

At the moment, all the three tabs contain the entire property list.
Is there any elegant way of doing this?

[image: The Tabs]

Thanks for your support, I will add more code if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

My solution was to create for each Tab a Selection class (implements `IPropertySource`)  and a Section class (extends `AbstractPropertySection`). Then I created a new class “wrapper”, that implements `ISelection` and contains an array of `ISelection`. In each Section class (i.e. `public  class InformationSection extends AbstractPropertySection`) I’ve used this “wrapper” class in `setInput` method from the `AbstractPropertySection` to store the `StructuredSelection` items. After that with `wrapper.getSelection()[0].getFirstElement` I accesed all properties of Information Tab.

I hope that my answer will help you.